# Detect browser's language with i18next-browser-languagedetector for reactJs web app

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have a reactJs application and I want to add localization to it. I have never used i18next before but I am trying to get used to it. My problem is, I cannot detect user's browser's in use language. This is my code could you please help me with some code, I have searched all documents and answers for this topic but I could not find any solution.

**This is my i18n.js file and I am importing this in files that I want to use**

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import languageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
i18next
    .use(languageDetector)
    .init({
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: "en",
        resources: {
            en: {
                translation: {
                    "table": {
                        "fortuneId": "FortuneId",
                        "name": "Name",
                        "age": "Age",
                        "date": "Date",
                        "relationship": "Relationship",
                        "note": "Note",
                        "topic": "Topic",
                        "question": "Question",
                        "gender": "Gender",
                        "rejected": "Rejected"
                    },

                    "auth": {
                        "signIn": "Sign In",
                        "signOut": "Sign Out",
                        "joinUs": "Join Us",
                        "goBack": "Go Back",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "username": "Username",
                        "password": "Password",
                    },

                    "admin": {
                        "employee": "Employees",
                        "moderator": "Moderator",
                        "admin": "Admin",
                        "refreshCounters": "Refresh Counters",
                        "refreshCounter": "Refresh Counter",
                        "setAsEmployee": "Set as Employee",
                        "setAsAdmin": "Set as Admin",
                        "setAsModerator": "Set as Moderator",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "password": "Password",
                        "answeredFortunes": "Answered Fortunes",
                        "controlledFortunes": "Controlled Fortunes",
                    },

                    "moderator": {
                        "approve": "Approve",
                        "reject": "Reject",
                        "topic": "Topic",
                        "name": "Name",
                        "age": "Age",
                        "date": "Date",
                        "relationship": "Relationship",
                        "gender": "Gender",
                        "answer": "Answer"
                    },

                    "answer": {
                        "fortuneId": "FortuneId",
                        "name": "Name",
                        "age": "Age",
                        "date": "Date",
                        "relationship": "Relationship",
                        "note": "Note",
                        "topic": "Topic",
                        "question": "Question",
                        "gender": "Gender",
                        "send": "Send",
                        "rejectionReason": "Rejection Reason",
                        "rejection": "Rejection",
                        "rejectedAnswer": "Rejected Answer",
                        "unassign": "Unassign"
                    },

                    "modal": {
                        "fortuneId": "FortuneId",
                        "name": "Name",
                        "age": "Age",
                        "date": "Date",
                        "relationship": "Relationship",
                        "note": "Note",
                        "topic": "Topic",
                        "question": "Question",
                        "gender": "Gender",
                        "assignToMe": "Assign to Me",
                        "cancel": "Cancel"
                    },

                    "profile": {
                        "name": "Name",
                        "age": "Age",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "answeredFortunes": "Answered Fortunes",
                        "controlledFortunes": "Controlled Fortunes",
                        "employeeTypeAdmin": "Admin",
                        "employeeTypeModerator": "Moderator",
                        "employeeTypeEmployee": "Employee",
                    },

                    "errors": {},
                }
            },
            tr: {
                translation: {
                    "table": {
                        "fortuneId": "FalId",
                        "name": "Ad",
                        "age": "Yaş",
                        "date": "Tarih",
                        "relationship": "İlişki Durumu",
                        "note": "Not",
                        "topic": "Konu",
                        "question": "Soru",
                        "gender": "Cinsiyet",
                        "rejected": "Reddedildi"
                    },

                    "auth": {
                        "signIn": "Giriş Yap",
                        "signOut": "Çıkış Yap",
                        "joinUs": "Bize Katıl",
                        "goBack": "Geri Dön",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "username": "Kullanıcı Adı",
                        "password": "Şifre",
                    },

                    "admin": {
                        "employee": "Yorumcu",
                        "moderator": "Moderatör",
                        "admin": "Admin",
                        "refreshCounters": "Sayaçları Sıfırla",
                        "refreshCounter": "Sayacı Sıfırla",
                        "setAsEmployee": "Yorumcu Yap",
                        "setAsAdmin": "Admin Yap",
                        "setAsModerator": "Moderatör Yap",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "password": "Şifre",
                        "answeredFortunes": "Gönderilen Fallar",
                        "controlledFortunes": "Kontrol Edilen Fallar",
                    },

                    "moderator": {
                        "approve": "Onayla",
                        "reject": "Reddet",
                        "topic": "Konu",
                        "name": "Ad",
                        "age": "Yaş",
                        "date": "Tarih",
                        "relationship": "İlişki Durumu",
                        "gender": "Cinsiyet",
                        "answer": "Fal Gönderi"
                    },

                    "answer": {
                        "fortuneId": "FalId",
                        "name": "Ad",
                        "age": "Yaş",
                        "date": "Tarih",
                        "relationship": "İlişki Durumu",
                        "note": "Not",
                        "topic": "Konu",
                        "question": "Soru",
                        "gender": "Cinsiyet",
                        "send": "Gönder",
                        "rejectionReason": "Reddedilme Nedeni",
                        "rejection": "Reddedilme",
                        "rejectedAnswer": "Reddedilen Gönder",
                        "unassign": "Fal'ı Bırak"
                    },

                    "modal": {
                        "fortuneId": "FalId",
                        "name": "Ad",
                        "age": "Yaş",
                        "date": "Tarih",
                        "relationship": "İlişki Durumu",
                        "note": "Not",
                        "topic": "Konu",
                        "question": "Soru",
                        "gender": "Yaş",
                        "assignToMe": "Bana Ata",
                        "cancel": "İptal"
                    },

                    "profile": {
                        "name": "Ad",
                        "age": "Yaş",
                        "email": "E-mail",
                        "answeredFortunes": "Gönderilen Fallar",
                        "controlledFortunes": "Kontrol Edilen Fallar",
                        "employeeTypeAdmin": "Admin",
                        "employeeTypeModerator": "Moderatör",
                        "employeeTypeEmployee": "Yorumcu",
                    },

                    "errors": {},
                }
            }
        }
    });

export default i18next;
```

**In those files I use this like**

```
   import i18next from "../../Localization/i18n";
   <div>
     {i18next.t('table.question')}
   </div>
```

This shows me "Question" in web page but if I change my google chrome browser to Turkish, it is still in english. I do not know what I am missing.

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: try `whitelist: [
    'en',
    'tr',
  ],
` option

Comment: not working :/ chrome turkish but it displays "Question". It should be "Soru" in turkish @xadm

Comment: `load: 'languageOnly',` for exclude region; detected lng can be cached, stored in cookie/localstorage ... clear cookie, use uri `?lng=LANGUAGE`, other browser/machine ... it can lready work properly but fooling you.

Comment: Is there any possibility to disable cach, localstroge, cookie check? Also I did not understand "?lng=LANGUAGE" thing :/ Can you provide any example? By the way thank you for your care :) @xadm

Comment: www.example.com/route/?lng=tr

Comment: you’ve set debug to true... what is your chrome console saying? Can you paste dome logs?

Answer (score 12):

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.  I tried @Ergin 's answer above but that didn't work, and Typescript was throwing errors about passing `0 params` when I used this suggestion:

```
//*** call without param to use language detector
i18n.changeLanguage()
```

The documentation doesn't exactly give you the full picture of how to set up detection, and then I found a [closed Github issue](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector/issues/174) where several people were asking a reasonable question, and the maintainers were kinda rude in their responses but also happened to supply a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-example-5w0ny?file=/src/i18n.js:141-150) that should have been in the documentation. It cleared up my issue with a few small adjustments from what the current documentation states to do.

I was then able to get language detection in my url with `https:www.domain.com?lng=es` as well as when using a browser extension that let me change the browser language.

Heres my working `i18n.ts` file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import XHR from "i18next-http-backend" // <---- add this

import commonDe from './locales/de/common.json'
import commonEn from './locales/en/common.json'
import commonEs from './locales/es/common.json'
import commonFr from './locales/fr/common.json'

const resources = {
  de: { common: commonDe },
  en: { common: commonEn },
  es: { common: commonEs },
  fr: { common: commonFr }
}

const options = {
  order: ['querystring', 'navigator'],
  lookupQuerystring: 'lng'
}

i18n
  .use(XHR) // <---- add this
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    // lng: 'en' // <--- turn off for detection to work
    detection: options,
    resources,
    ns: ['common'],
    defaultNS: 'common',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    supportedLngs: ['de', 'en', 'es', 'fr'],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    debug: false,
  })

export default i18n
```

(bonus help - if theres anyone jammed up on this part)

I am working in a Next.js project, and the above file was loaded in the `project-root/pages/_app.tsx` file like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import '../i18n/i18n'

import '../public/styles.css'

const TacoFridayApp = ({ Component, pageProps}: AppProps): JSX.Element => {
  
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default TacoFridayApp
```

Answer (score 6):

this helped me.

(thanks to:  https://velog.io/@hyounglee/TIL-80)

```
 import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import XHR from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

import translationEn from "../src/lang/translation.en.json";
import translationKo from "../src/lang/translation.ko.json";

const languages = ["en", "ko"]; // (*)

const resource = {
  en: {
    translation: translationEn,
  },
  ko: {
    translation: translationKo,
  },
};

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    // detection: options,
    detection: { order: ["path", "navigator"] },
    fallbackLng: "en",
    resources: resource,
    whitelist: languages,
    //lng: "ko",
    // ns: ['translation'],
    // defaultNS: "translation",
    debug: true,

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 6):

ran into this issue myself, changing my browser's default language does nothing
[image]

But everything make sense after I look into the documentation https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector

```
// order and from where user language should be detected
  order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'subdomain'],
```

The i18next language detector first check queryString, that's why using http://localhost:3000?lng=es work, since it is the first thing it check.

Then next check cookie, then next I check localStorage and found english is stored. [image]

Deleting this value and refresh the page, I see the page is updated to the new language

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game but hopefully can benefit the community, I've started working with `react-i18next` recently and also ran into this problem.  I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37328178/1968395) which has a sublink which points to this line in the source:

https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/ee3afd8e5d958e8d703a208194e59fa5228165fd/src/i18next.js#L189

```
if (!lng && this.services.languageDetector) lng = this.services.languageDetector.detect();
```

This shows that if you call `changeLanguage()` without any arguments it will attempt to do language detection based on the priority you have configured.  So to get this working I do the following:

```
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en",
    detection: detectOptions,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

//*** call without param to use language detector
i18n.changeLanguage()
```

After doing this the URL query parameter now works, for example:

`www.example.com/route/?lng=tr`

Comment: So far I have not been able to get the language detection to successfully work based on Browser language language though :( so that's still not working.  If anyone has any thoughts would appreciate it.

Comment: if you are using LanguageDetector shouldn't you not specify lng:en  as said in the documentation?