# Is it ok to change the language of a webpage by changing state?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if `setState` is a good way of changing language on a web page. To be more precise, I have a form and I want to allow the user to toggle between two languages, let's say "EN" and "FR". I created two buttons for each language, and passed two different functions for the `onClick` event which changes the state:

```
this.state = {
   message : "Hello"
}
```

**setState**

```
handleEN() {
   this.setState( 
   message : "Hello"
)}


handleFR() {
   this.setState( 
   message : "Bonjour"
)}
```

**The buttons:**

```
 <button onClick={this.handleEN}> EN </button>
 <button onClick={this.handleFR}> FR </button>
```

**Display:**

```
<h1> {this.state.message} </h1>
```

I already can see a problem with this method since I have to change state to English even though the initial state was "hello". I've read about the `react-intl` and `i18n` libraries, but I would like to hear which route I should go regarding page translation and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your use case. If this is entirely what you want to achieve like just for this page you have a button to translate just this particular section then this is ok,but i doubt that would be the case in the long run. So if your plan is something like clicking on FR should change everything on a page then you should go with something globally applicable dealing with that inside each components state would become tedious and prone to errors and bugs.

I suggest looking at this discussion to further clarify your needs to go for a global approach. 
[Changing React Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728632/react-i18next-and-correct-way-of-changing-language?rq=1)